# ReactJS First fetch is undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch

I'm doing a simple fetch from my backend express server.

1. First "Submit" button click, I get "undefined".
2. Second time "Submit" button click, I get my data as expected.

[image]

This would work but the user would need to click login twice (not ideal)

How can I get the results from the user's first click?

```
import React  from "react";
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, FormLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Login.css";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: []
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))

      console.log(this.state.data[0]);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup controlId="email" bssize="large">
            <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              autoFocus
              type="email"
              value={this.email}
              //onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="password" bssize="large">
            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              value={this.password}
            // onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              type="password"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button block bssize="large" type="submit">
            Login
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

***For testing, I'm using "console.log(this.state.data[0]);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState doesn't reflect immediately. You might have to pass the console.log as a callback to setState

Change from

```
.then(data => this.setState({ data }))
```

to

```
 .then(data => this.setState({ data }, ()=>{console.log(this.state.data[0])}))
```

To know more about the callback and the issue.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Even if `setState` *was* synchronous, it still wouldn't work in his question lol cos it's inside a fetch's `.then`, where as the `console.log` is outside that chain

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you mean by setState as synchronous. setState is async and if you want to know when the update is done, you need to pass the required function as a callback.  And in the answer I asked the OP to print the log inside the callback.